# use robocopy for copy bigdata in python

Tags: python, robocopy

i have this code for copy data :

```
from subprocess import call, check_call
 
call(["robocopy",'\\\\127.0.0.1\\Backup', '\\\\127.0.0.2\\h\\SQL BACKUP\\a',"/S"])
```

How can I access the data inside the terminal ????

I need to have access to the values that run after executing the above code snippet

output terminal like this :
[image]

Comment: Have roboopy create a log file: https://superuser.com/a/989217

Comment: You did not understand my need

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was to write the output to the file and then open the file and call its columns
The final code for copying information was as follows

```
from subprocess import call

path = 'C:\\Bot\\'

call(["robocopy",'\\\\127.0.0.1\\Backup', '\\\\127.0.0.2\\h\\a\\ss',"/S","/MIR",f"/LOG:{path}Backup.log"])
```